# Shell command won't run in Docker build

Tags: linux, bash, docker

When I am inside the container, the following works:

`pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)`

Yet when I try to do the same in my Dockerfile like this:

`RUN pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)`

I get:

```
------
 > [ 7/10] RUN pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze):
#11 0.182 /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)]: exit code: 2
```

How do I re-write this command to make it happy?

#### Edit:

I am using this work around. Still interested in the one-liner answer however

```
RUN pip freeze > to_delete.txt
RUN pip uninstall -y -r to_delete.txt
```

Comment: `RUN pip uninstall -y -r <\(pip freeze\)`

Comment: That doesn't work, I get: `------
 > [ 7/10] RUN pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze):
#11 0.206 /bin/sh: 1: cannot open (pip: No such file
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip uninstall -y -r <\(pip freeze\)]: exit code: 2`

Comment: However, this works for one package (without the redirected input): `RUN pip uninstall plotly -y`

Comment: Basically duplicate of [Difference between `sh` and `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default `shell` for `RUN` is `sh` which looks not compatiable with above command.

You could change the shell for `RUN` to `bash` to make it work.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN pip install pyyaml
RUN pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)
```

**Execution:**

```
$ docker build -t abc:1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   5.12kB
Step 1/4 : FROM python:3
 ---> da24d18bf4bf
Step 2/4 : SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
 ---> Running in da64b8004392
Removing intermediate container da64b8004392
 ---> 4204713810f9
Step 3/4 : RUN pip install pyyaml
 ---> Running in 17a91e8cc768
Collecting pyyaml
  Downloading PyYAML-5.4.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (630 kB)
Installing collected packages: pyyaml
Successfully installed pyyaml-5.4.1
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.3.3; however, version 21.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Removing intermediate container 17a91e8cc768
 ---> 1e6dba7439ac
Step 4/4 : RUN pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)
 ---> Running in 256f7194350c
Found existing installation: PyYAML 5.4.1
Uninstalling PyYAML-5.4.1:
  Successfully uninstalled PyYAML-5.4.1
Removing intermediate container 256f7194350c
 ---> 10346fb83333
Successfully built 10346fb83333
Successfully tagged abc:1
```

Comment: Thank you. I see in places people use `SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c" ]` does the `login` do anything helpful?

Comment: This related to `login shell` VS `non login shell`, login shell will execute `.bashrc` etc. when user login into system while `non login shell` not. But in docker scenario, I don't think there are any difference as we won't depend on this feature.

Comment: Thank you. I have a follow on question here, if I could ask another favor... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69052362/how-to-ignore-a-docker-build-step-fail